# I am trying to compile this code please review

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string dna1;

getline(cin, dna1);

string dna2;

getline(cin, dna2);

int hammingDistance=0;

for (int i=0; i < dna1.length(); ++i) {

if (dna1[i] !=dna2[i]) {

hammingDistance++;

}

}

cout <<"HammingDistance is: " << hammingDistance << '\n’;

}
```

> So this is the code I have compiled but it seems to have some error this is from the website Rosalind to which I have added the link below:http://rosalind.info/problems/hamm/

Comment: it's missing `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>`.  Thre is also something odd in the '\n' onthe last line.  It's probably som UTF error, simply delete that and retype it.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael Roy commented, you're missing the header files you need, iostream and string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

You need to format your code though. As it is, it's hard to read, in a regular production-size project, it would be impossible. I also don't recommend using  the "using namespace std;" declaration. It's a bad beginner habit to get into.

Everyone has their own specific preferences, but this is roughly what your code should look like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string dna1;
    std::cin >> dna1;
    //getline(cin, dna1);

    std::string dna2;
    std::cin >> dna2;
    //getline(cin, dna2);

    int hammingDistance = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < dna1.length(); ++i) {
        if (dna1[i] != dna2[i]) {
            hammingDistance++;
        }
    }

    std::cout <<"HammingDistance is: " << hammingDistance << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I used the standard stream methods for input for consistency, but there's nothing technically wrong with other methods, as long as you don't use gets().